# Intellij Parallel Running Configuration Limit

Tags: intellij-idea

I am trying to run multiple Java Applications from Intellij. But after starting 10 applications the start icon becomes disabled and I am not able to start any more Applications.

Is there any limit set in IntelliJ about number of applications I can run in parallel. If so, can I change it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do all these 10 apps continue to run at the same time?

Comment: Yes, all are running at same time.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Maybe you could provide a sample project and the details how exactly you start them?

Comment: These are separate spring-boot Microservices which I have imported into single project. And I am starting them individually as Application (Edit Configuration->Application). So there are like 15 microservices that need to be started, but after start 10 services the run option is disabled.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any limit for that in IntelliJ IDEA. If you can't run more than 10, please file a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the sample project and the steps to reproduce. Also attach [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/207241085).